# Can someone show me a code example showing how to serialize an object to JSON?

Tags: c#, json, azure

I have:

```
    MemoryStream stream1 = new MemoryStream();
    DataContractJsonSerializer s = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(UserTask));
    s.WriteObject(stream1, task);
    stream1.Position = 0;
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(stream1);
    Trace.Write("JSON form of Person object: ");
    Trace.WriteLine(sr.ReadToEnd());
    string json = sr.ReadToEnd();

    ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();

    byte[] data = encoding.GetBytes(json);

    logger.Write("Attempting to post the foillowing JSON data: " + json);
    Trace.WriteLine("Attempting to post the foillowing JSON data: " + json);
    // Make a post to the other service
    HttpWebRequest httpWReq =
        (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(@"https://some.company.url");
        //(HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(@"https://some.company.url");


    httpWReq.Method = "POST";
    httpWReq.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    httpWReq.ContentLength = data.Length;

    using (Stream stream = httpWReq.GetRequestStream())
    {
        stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
    }
    HttpWebResponse response = null;
    string responseString = null;
    try
    {
        // Do some work that may result in a transient fault.
        retryPolicy.ExecuteAction(
          () =>
          {
              // Call a method that uses Windows Azure storage and which may
              // throw a transient exception. 
              response = (HttpWebResponse)httpWReq.GetResponse();
              responseString = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
          });
    }
```

This isn't actually sending JSON across the wire to the other service... 
I am using DataContractJsonSerializer because the data contains a dictionary. I can post what the data looks like if it's useful, but that part is working I think?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I personally prefer using [Json.Net from James Newton-King](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx).

Install the nuget package.
[image]

Next, just serialize it.

```
var users = GetUsersFromDatabase();
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(users, Formatting.Indented);
```

If you have some json and you wish to convert that into a rich object, then we can deserialize it easily.

In this example, lets image we have a txt file which contains the users, in a valid json format...

```
var usersText = File.ReadAllText("C:\\Temp\\JsonUsers.txt");
var users = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IList<User>>(usersText);
```

Comment: Does this work with dictionaries with varied types of values?

Comment: Yes. rich objects work with this. Simple to try :) Proof: RavenDb uses this *under the covers* and it serializes/deserializes all types of complex objects, like Dictionaries.

Answer (score 2):

[JavaScriptSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx) is often a good approach.

```
var json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(task);
```

Comment: IDictionary gets serialized as key-value pairs. Use [Json.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx) if you want to emit a JS associative array.

Answer (score 1):

JSON.NET is the default library used by ASP.NET MVC for JSON. You can get it using nuget then use the static class JsonConvert.

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(task);
```

Comment: This wont work for dictionaries with varied type values, it says so right in the docs.